# Ruby on Rails "bin/rails routes" and "bin/rails server" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rubygems

Recently started learning Ruby on Rails to build up a web API, code with VS code, following the youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KqbPJtA5O8&list=PLbTv9eGiI03u1-JFkFpPGsR_hMre6WX3e

After installing everything, create a project with `rails new apiproject --api`

And the next step is to check the routes with `bin/rails routes` and got the error

```
Error: Command 'routes' not recognized
Did you mean: `$ rake routes` ?

Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
```

In the video, it supposed to return
[image]

I have tried `rake route` but the result is not what I expected as in the video.

After that, I tried to start the server first with `bin/rails server`, and I keep getting the error:

```
/Users/jolin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:85: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
/Users/jolin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/jolin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        9377: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        9376: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        9375: from /Users/jolin/Desktop/RoR/liborapi/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        9374: from /Users/jolin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        9373: from /Users/jolin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        9372: from /Users/jolin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/spring-4.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        9371: from /Users/jolin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/spring-4.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        9370: from /Users/jolin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/spring-4.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
         ... 9365 levels...
           4: from /Users/jolin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
           3: from /Users/jolin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
           2: from /Users/jolin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
           1: from /Users/jolin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/Users/jolin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

I previous got `undefined method <class:BigDecimal>` error, but after add `gem 'bigdecimal', '1.4.2'` to Gemfile, it resolved, but I couldn't find a way to solve this issue.

I have so struggled even in the very first step, I have tried to upgrade/downgrade my Ruby and Rails in a different versions...

My current versions:
**Ruby**: **ruby 2.7.0p0** (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin19]
**Rails**: **Rails 4.2.2**
(But with rails -v, I always got Deprecation warning: Expected string default value for '--rc'; got false (boolean).
This will be rejected in the future unless you explicitly pass the options `check_default_type: false` or call `allow_incompatible_default_type!` in your code
You can silence deprecations warning by setting the environment variable THOR_SILENCE_DEPRECATION.)
**rvm**: **rvm 1.29.12** (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
**gem**: **3.1.2**

**Update**
After trying upgrade ruby, downgrade ruby, downgrade rails
I am now keeping getting error as below while I run `bin/rails server`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        3: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        2: from /Users/jolin/Desktop/RoR/liborapi/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from /Users/jolin/Desktop/RoR/liborapi/bin/spring:10:in `read'
/Users/jolin/Desktop/RoR/liborapi/bin/spring:10:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/jolin/Desktop/RoR/liborapi/Gemfile.lock (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running it in Ruby 2.5.3 as in the screen shot. I don't think Rails 4.2 is tested or supported in ruby 2.7. You could also try installing the later version of ruby 2.7.6.

Current version of rails is 7.0.x, and Ruby 3.1.x.

Segmentation fault is usually a result of Ruby installation, you can try installing ruby 2.7.6 and try again.

Comment: I tried to upgrade ruby to 2.7.6, and got the same error, then I tried to downgrade ruby to 2.5.3 then got `in warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)`

Comment: I tried to downgrad bundler as well, but would get `sqlite3-1.5.2-x86_64-darwin requires ruby version >= 2.6, <3.2.dev, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.5.3p105`, which needs my ruby to be newer version : (

Answer (score 0):

The `rails routes` command was introduced with Ruby on Rails 5.0. In versions prior 5.0 it was called `rake routes`.

This means because of the old version of Rails you are using you can simply call `rake routes` and get the same response.

But it is worth noting that the youtube video you are following is about Ruby on Rails 6.0. But you are using Ruby on Rails 4.2.2. Your local environment is 2 major versions and more than 4 years behind. You will very likely face more compatibility issues when you continue working with such an ancient and unmaintained version of Ruby on Rails.

I suggest that you upgrade your local environment to at least Ruby 2.7 and Ruby on Rails 6.2 or even better Ruby 3.1 and Ruby on Rails 7.0. There is no benefit in learning Rails is outdated and unmaintained versions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the same issue

**Don't use** *`bin/rails routes`* command
***just*** use *`rails routes`*

This will solve your problem just let me know whether this work or not for you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33662651)